# How to prevernt Facebook to aggregate links on the wall

Tags: facebook, aggregation

We have a javascript toolbar which being injected into sites. on our toolbar we have an ability to share something (on facebook) inside a page.
 
The URL that we are generating is something like http://somedomain.com/page1#ourtag=1234.
 
Now, if a user decided to share more than 1 thing on the same page, for eample :

http://somedomain.com/page1#ourtag=1234

http://somedomain.com/page1#ourtag=5678

Facebook aggregates the links and show them on the wall as :
http://somedomain.com/page1

any idea how we can define in Open Graph some rule that will prevent facebook from doing this link aggregation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/explicit_sharing/ the difference between status updates and explicit implicit updates

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alon, I have tried to use explicit/implicit but nothing did the trick.